# how to convert a set to an equivalent set?

Tags: real-analysis

I am doing homework

I have the following defition $-A$ = {$-y$ : $y\in A^c$}, I would like convert it to a expression like $-A$ = {$y$ : anything}

set $A$ is a dedekind cut

Comment: Well, $-A =\{y: -y \in A^c\}$.....

Comment: Actually isn't the definition supposes to be $-A = \{-y|y \in A\}$  (not $A^c$).  Then you want $-A = \{y|-y \in A\}$

Comment: Thank you very much, A is a dedekind cut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication by $-1$ is invertible, so you have $-A = \{ y : -y \in A^c \}$.